# Adding SuperInstruction to JVM

Tags: jvm, bytecode, java, jvm-hotspot

i have to add new **SuperInstructions** to the Java which is a replacement of some sequence of instructions in the bytecode. I have gone through many research articles but the file names which should be updated are not mentioned in any of the article.
Can anyone please identify me the **hotspot** file(s) which contain the **Main Interpreter Loop** of the JVM having the case statements in any architecture like X86, ARM etc.
In other words, i need location of the file which contain the **opcodes** so that i can modify them.

Comment: I would look for the files which mention existing byte code instructions

Comment: @PeterLawrey , The articles mentioned that there is a main switch case loop containing code for each Instruction of Java Bytecode. I have to modify it and add new instructions in it. Thanks in advance for your support

Comment: I assume that article is talking about how it could be implemented, I suspect the JVM is more complicated/optimised.

Comment: If you just want to learn something maybe try a simpler JVM than hotspot. If you're doing this for commercial applications maybe you shouldn't offload your basic sleuthing on others. It's complex software and a moving target, reading an article is probably not sufficient to get into development. Maybe take a look at the [openjdk wiki](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/Main)

Comment: @the8472, it looks supporting. let me check it. thanks

Comment: Why do you “have to” add these new instructions? What kind of problem should they solve?

Comment: @Holger my task is to observe the performance improvement on different benchmarks. basically it is like compression of bytecode so that size of bytecode may decrease as well. any further guidance / tutorial / wiki / documentation regarding how to add new instructions to any one architecture only. ?

Comment: Of course, creating a single instruction to represent a sequence of multiple instructions can have the outcome of acting like a compression, but how does this relate to the benchmarking you’re talking about? What are you benchmarking, the not-yet-existing special handling of these macro instructions or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a new instruction is not an easy task if you are not familiar with HotSpot source code. This is not a matter of modifying just a few locations; this rather involves many JVM parts, including

- [Bytecode interpreter](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/b756e7a2ec33/src/share/vm/interpreter) and Constant Pool resolver;
- [Verifier](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/b756e7a2ec33/src/share/vm/classfile/verifier.cpp);
- [OopMap generator](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/b756e7a2ec33/src/share/vm/oops/generateOopMap.cpp);
- [C1](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/b756e7a2ec33/src/share/vm/c1) and [C2](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/b756e7a2ec33/src/share/vm/opto) compilers with their parsers, optimizers and code generators.
- probably, other parts, depending on what your new instruction does.

Furthermore, HotSpot JVM does not have a *'Main Interpreter Loop'* at all. Instead there is a so-called *'template interpreter'* which is generated at runtime when JVM starts. For each bytecode there is a platform-dependent assembly-like template that generates interpreter snippet for execution of this bytecode in all possible top-of-stack states. Each template typically ends with a sequence that dispatches to the next bytecode.

To get an idea how x86 template interpreter looks like, see [src/cpu/x86/vm/templateTable_x86.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/b756e7a2ec33/src/cpu/x86/vm/templateTable_x86.cpp). New instructions will require a similar template.

Comment: i have to work on the performance improvement on different benchmarks. can you please guide me about any wiki / documentation having such information. thanks for your reply

Comment: @adeeliqbal The best HotSpot documentation is its [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/tip). Seriously.

Comment: what if i need just to modify its interpreter? i have to add superinstructions to the code which is replacement of more than one old instructions. what to do in this case?

Comment: @adeeliqbal Look for `RewriteFrequentPairs` in the code. This feature is very close to what you are going to do.